# Create peer to peer connection in Java to receive and send message

Tags: java, sockets

Create peer to peer connection in Java to receive and send message.

All i want is to know if it is possible to have some pseudocode;

```
user 1:
1.create connection with port ip;
3. send message
6. receive message


user 2;
2. receive notification that there is a new connection
4. receive message
5. send message
```

I know that it can be done by using both user1 and user2 as client and server, but i don't want to have client and server for each one.

Comment: user2 has to be listening when the connection happens.  That means [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) (or maybe a datagram socket, but datagrams are passé.)